# Ref Class vs Ref Struct, what's the difference?

Tags: c#, class, struct

```
public struct StructHouse{
public int number;
}


public class ClassHouse{
public int number;
}


public class Test{
public TestForStruct testForStruct;
public ClassHouse classHouse = new ClassHouse();
public StructHouse structHouse = new StructHouse();

SendRef1(ref classHouse);
testForStruct.SendRef2(ref structHouse);
}

public class TestForStruct{
public StructHouse structHouse;

public void (ref classHouse);
public void SendRef2(ref StructHouse structHouse){
this.structHouse = structHouse;
this.structHouse.number = 1;      //THIS DOESN'T UPDATE THE VALUE FOR 'Test'
//BUT IT DOES UPDATE IF I SEND REF CLASS INSTEAD OF REF STRUCT
}
```

e: if I change the reference value for 'number' in 'SendRef1', the value is updated in the class Test, but it's not updated when changing the value in SendRef2. Can anyone please explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-know-the-difference-passing-a-struct-and-passing-a-class-to-a-method this should give the answer

Comment: Without understanding your own knowledge of C#, the answer should be "no difference". What do *you* think the difference(s) may be?

Comment: @TimonPost sorry but it didn't make me understand.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not that new to C# but I never thought about the difference and I didn't find an explanation online that helped me.

Comment: When you use `ref`, the variable is passed rather than the value of the variable. That's true no matter the nature of the type of the variable. That's why it's important to know your own understanding/guesses.

Comment: It's really unclear what the question is. `struct` and `class` are two separate things in C#

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. I'd rather ask to make sure I understand it correctly. So if I only were to change the variables in the referenced struct and referenced class, the outcome is the same, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @UnholySheep If I only were to change the variables in the referenced struct and referenced class, will the outcome be the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using ref with class C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971170/using-ref-with-class-c-sharp)

Comment: "the variables in the referenced struct and referenced class" -- Those are fields, not variables. @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment is only about the one variable passed in in each case. It does have an effect on fields, but only indirectly, and it follows directly from the difference between value types (`struct`) and reference types (`class`). So again, what do you think the difference is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is copying the struct.

```
this.structHouse = structHouse;
```

You change the value of `number` only on the copy.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense. Thank you very much!